# NServiceBus ITransport events getting current message reference

Tags: nservicebus

I'm building some monitoring tooling around NServiceBus, at the moment i'm subscribing to a few events on the ITransport interface:

```
ITransport Events:
TransportMessageReceived 
FailedMessageProcessing
FinishedMessageProcessing
```

When subscribing to the `TransportMessageReceived` event I get a reference to the current message in the event args. However when the `FinishedMessageProcessing` event is raised it doesn't seem to contain a reference to the message that was completed. This is true for the `FailedMessageProcessing` event which contains the Exception but not the message that caused the exception.

I was wondering if there is some way to get a reference to the message when the FailedMessageProcessing and FinishedMessageProcessing events are raised

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For failed messages, you can implement the following interface to get a reference to the message:

```
 public interface IManageMessageFailures
{
    void SerializationFailedForMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e);

    void ProcessingAlwaysFailsForMessage(TransportMessage message, Exception e);

    void Init(Address address);

}
```

Please note that if you use this, then you won't be able to use Second Level Retries out of the box.